# Show hover menu on tab key press

Tags: javascript, html, css

On this website, I have images that you can hover over with your mouse and it will display two buttons. I want keyboard-only users to be able to tab through the site, so when they tab, the hoverable menu shows up. I've read a lot of solutions involving `:focus` and `tabindex=0` but I can't seem to make it work. I have attempted to put `tabindex=0` on the `<a>` tags to see if that would do it, but it doesn't. I believe the buttons will be tabbed through just fine if I could just get the hover menu to show up using the tab key. I might be missing something obvious, but I'm a beginner with all of these things. If it's not possible via CSS, can someone suggest a JS solution?

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail thumbnail-medium-short">
        <div class="nqspCover-container">
            <img src="img/stuff.jpg" alt="Front cover" width="180px" height="233px">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="read-button"><a href="urlhere">Read</a></div>
                <div class="buy-button"><a href="urlhere">Buy</a></div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="nqsp-caption">
            <p>stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nqspCover-container {
position: relative;
width: 180px;
height: 233px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.nqspCover-container:hover .overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.buy-button{
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.read-button, .buy-button{
    position: absolute;
    width: 65px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: solid 2px white;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.read-button a, .buy-button a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.nqspCover-container:hover .read-button,
.nqspCover-container:hover .buy-button{
    opacity: 1;
}

.read-button a:hover, .buy-button a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.read_button a:focus, .buy-button a:focus{
    display: block;
}
```

Example of the hover menu I need to pop up when they tab to it (don't worry, the background img and buttons definitely won't look like that when it's done):

[image: Hover menu]

Comment: @floor No, if you do that, sighted-users will not be able to see the buttons (hover will be gone) and the focus works on the buttons (I have to press tab twice, once for each button in the hover menu, before it'll visibly focus on another element on the page), but you cannot actually see it focusing on them because the hover menu isn't visible.

Comment: Only one element can have focus at a time, so you can not do this using `:focus` alone. That's what the [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) pseudo class was made to solve - but be aware of browser compatibility; MicroSofts two current browsers don't support it yet. You'll need a JS solution or at least a polyfill for `:focus-within`.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, that was helpful. So lets say in a magical world where all browsers support it, if I used focus-within and tabbed around the page, would pressing the tab key actually *make that menu appear* (not using anything but the keyboard) when it is given focus? I think that's what I'm really stuck on - I don't know if "focus" really does what I need it to do at all. I get that focus highlights elements in some fashion when they are tabbed or clicked, but will it actually make an element show if it is not already visible? I'm leaning toward no.

Comment: div elements can't receive focus by default, so you'd need to start by adding the `tabindex` attribute. _"I don't know if focus really does what I need it to do at all."_ - it does what the other pseudo classes do too, no more or less: Identify/react to an element being in a specific state. What you do with it, or it's descendants/siblings, is up to you - by writing the selectors that target those elements based on that state. https://www.google.com/search?q=menu+with+focus-within gets you more detailed explanations & examples, f.e. http://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/05/14/focus-within.html

Comment: Made an answer out of the comments, that should get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one element can have focus at a time, so you can not do this using `:focus` alone. That's what the [:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) pseudo class was made to solve - but be aware of browser compatibility; MicroSofts two current browsers don't support it yet.

You'll need a JS solution or at least a polyfill for `:focus-within`

---

(FYI, `div` elements can't receive focus by default, so you'd need to start by adding the `tabindex` attribute. `tabindex="0"` is usually what you want to make an element focus-able in normal DOM order.)

---

> I don't know if "focus" really does what I need it to do at all.

It does what the other pseudo classes do, too - no more or less: Identify/react to an element being in a specific state. What you do with it, or it's descendants/siblings, is up to you - by writing the selectors that target those elements, based on that parent/siblings state.

https://www.google.com/search?q=menu+with+focus-within gets you more detailed explanations & examples, f.e. http://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/05/14/focus-within.html That one explains the topic pretty well, and also mentions a polyfill, https://allyjs.io/api/style/focus-within.html